# KineticJS - anchors not remaining when resizing an image + issue with image remaining inside the boundary

Tags: kineticjs

Please see this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dipens/EAJ4f/1/):

I am trying to solve 2 problems here:

1) When I click on the anchor and then try to drag or resize it - the anchors disappear.

I tried doing:

```
anchor.on("dragend", function(e) {
    var node = e.targetNode;        
    if (node.parent.nodeType = 'Kinetic.Group') {
        var children = node.parent.children;
        selectedGroup = node.parent;     
        for (i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {             
            if (children[i].getName() == 'topLeft' ||
                children[i].getName() == 'topRight' ||
                children[i].getName() == 'bottomRight' ||
                children[i].getName() == 'bottomLeft') {
                children[i].show();
            }
        }
    }
```

but although I can see the anchors when I do a console.log, they don't appear on the canvas.
Ideally I don't want the anchors to disappear until the user does a single click on the image.  I know that when I start a drag or resize, the system is assuming I have done a single click and is removing them (instead of a click and hold down - ie to perform the drag or resize).

2) How would I make sure that if the user resizes the image so that it exceeds the black rectangle boundary - that it not increase the size anymore?  For example, if you drag Darth Vader to the right edge - and then increase its size using the bottom left anchor, the image spills over the right edge of the black rectangle - which is wrong.

Many Thanks for any help on these matters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `mousedown`, use the `click` events. Then all you need is a flag called `moving` to detect whether you moved the mouse (ie. dragged or resized) before deciding to `deselect()` or not.

At the top declare a new `var moving`

Then change your events to handle `moving`:

```
layer.on('mousedown', function (e) {
    moving = false;
});

layer.on('mousemove', function () {
    moving = true;
});

layer.on('click', function (e) {
    var node = e.targetNode;
    select(node);
});
```

And then modify your `else` clause inside your `select()` function:

```
else {
  if(!moving) {
    deselect();
  }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/86uWn/)

**NOTE:** Personally, I think it's more functional to deselect (hide your anchors) when you click away from the image, rather than click on the image AGAIN to hide anchors. This is probably even easier to implement! It's your choice though.

As for your second question, I already answered this in one of your previous questions, so I'm not going to code it for you because I think you can figure it out, but if you use a `dragBoundFunc` on the anchor (similar to your `dragBoundFunc` for your `group`), it will prevent your anchors from sometimes bleeding out of the edge.

**EDIT:**

You can use a dragBoundFunc on your anchor when you declare `var anchor` in your `addAnchor()` function:

```
var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    stroke: "#666",
    fill: "#ddd",
    strokeWidth: 2,
    radius: 8,
    name: name,
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
      //..code similar to your group dragBoundFunc
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply.  How would you declare the dragBoundFunc on the anchor (don't need implementation)? I tried ` anchor.on("dragBoundFunc"), function(pos) {` but that doesn't work?  Or do you mean to say that I need to write another function that is similar to the dragBoundFunc used by the group? Thanks!

Comment: You have to write another function similar to the one your wrote for the group, except for the anchor when you create it in the function addAnchor()

Comment: Edited answer above to show how you can use the dragBoundFunc for your anchors.